# Вопрос по шаблонизатору в php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос, пишу движки ради практики, и пишу я без каких либо шаблонизаторов типа Smarty и т.д.,и вот сам вопрос, это не плохо? или очень желательно писать в каком либо шаблонизаторе,и почему

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Пишу движок, всё своё, изобрёл велосипед, своё редактировать проще, ошибки исправлять. "Если жизнь наша станет проще, мы превратимся в обезьян"

Comment: у вас тоже вперемешку php и html )? или изобрели какой либо для себя стиль написания движков

Comment: поверьте пхп и хтмл всегда будут вместе)) я так же изобретал велосипед под себя. свои правила написания шаблона и так далее. если работаешь один то лучше так, если в команде то придется смотреть что они используют. правил написания шаблонов достаточное количество. так что не мучайтесь, для себя старайтесь сами привести код к удобному и не громоздкому.

Comment: всем спасибо

Comment: Пхп и хтмл не перемешивал, шаблоны хранятся в базе данных, установлено кеширование в 100 сек дабы не нагружать базу, положения компонентов отмечаются мини-тегами $MENU$ $BOTTOM_MENU$ $CONTENT_PAGE$, после чтения шаблона регуляркой получаю список компонентов, функции соответствующие названиям мини-тегов, заменяю имена мини-тегов на результаты работы функций. Ну вот в общем логика моего шаблонизатора) Вот как это работает : http://t.pwon.pp.ua/laSearch/take_test/ , исходниками пока не делюсь. Нижний компонент авторизации и регистрации ещё не дописан.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы собираетесь продавать движки или давать сторонним программистам возможность их расширения, то без шаблонизатора будет туго. Шаблонизатор может быть организован несколькими способами.

1. Шаблонизатор как отдельный класс. Позволяет четко выделить представление и отличается наличием шаблонов без псевдоязыка. Пример этого можно встретить в Abo.CMS - там в папке tpl лежит пачка (кипа/куча/воз и маленькая тележка) шаблонов .html.
2. Шаблонизатор, совмещающий логику и представление. Выводимые значения заранее заносятся в массивы, названия которых одинаковы для всех шаблонов. Принцип: формируем массив - подключаем шаблон - выводим все, что накопилось. Пример тому - Битрикс.
3. Шаблонизатор на уровне вывода компонентов (Joomla, хотя и не уверен). Принцип: на страницу внедряются метки с параметрами компонентов, а компоненты уже сами решают, как и что выводить.

В принципе, можно придумать и свой вариант шаблонизатора. Главное ведь - чтобы было удобно разработчику, в том числе и стороннему.